# Rails instance validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I was trying to practice `Rspec`, but seems I was confused about some rails part.

Here is **Zombie.rb**

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    has_many :tweets
    def hungry?
        true
    end
end
```

It seems when I create a Zombie instance, it will check the `name` attribute.
So, I wrote these `Rspec` code.

```
it 'should not be hungry after eating' do 
        @zombie = Zombie.create 
        @zombie.should_not be_valid
        @zombie.hungry?.should be_truthy
    end
```

Why it will pass? If the `@zombie` is not valid, why `@zombie.hungry?` will still return `true`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because your `hungry?` method always returns `true`

`be_truthy  # passes if obj is truthy (not nil or false)` even if your 
object is nil it's returns true

[be_truthy](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/be-matchers)

`z = Zombie.create` -  It will not be created because of validation

```
z.hungry? => true
```

so your test passed

Comment: Um...maybe I was stuck on something wrong, I was trying to say why I can call a instance method without a valid instance?

Comment: ok, I see. Thanks. It's a silly question, I didn't know a nil instance can still call method, I thought it will be error or something.

Comment: I think  `z.hungry?` should return `true` not nil.

Comment: @CodaChang fix typo

Answer (score 2):

`hungry?` will always return `true`, therefore your expectation always passes.

That your instance is invalid doesn't mean that the instance is not valid Ruby. It is still a fully functional instance. The `valid?` method returns `false`, because the values of this instance are not valid to *you*, since you defined that it is not valid to *you* without a name.

From Ruby's point of view it is still a valid `Zombie` instance.

Btw since you just started to learn RSpec. You use the old RSpec syntax, you might want to learn the new syntax instead which would look like this:

```
describe Zombie do
  context 'without a name' do
    subject(:zombie) { Zombie.new }

    it 'is not valid' do
      expect(zombie).to_not be_valid
    end

    it 'is hungry' do
      expect(zombie).to be_hungry
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your explain, it's really helpful.

Comment: It seems `be_invalid`, not `not_be_valid`